# .net Core API not working on IIS

Tags: api, .net-core, iis-7.5

I'm new to this .NET Core stuff and this is the first time I've tried to deploy one of these.

The project is an API for an Angular front end I'm building and takes HTTP requests and returns JSON.  When I run it in Visual Studio on my box it is all fine.  I'm running VS2017 and have .NET Core 2.0.0 installed.

I publish to a folder on the web server and it all seems to work fine, but when I try to access the API I get a 404 not found error.  The server is running .NET 2.0.6 (I tried to get 2.0.0 but couldn't find it in the Hosting Bundle Installer.

If I delete the web.config the HTML file will then show up, but obviously the API doesn't work.  But as the HTML file shows up there is no issue with permissions and access.  There's nothing in the Event Viewer.  I've also tried turning on the logging in the web.config, but it doesn't log... probably not getting far enough to.

Web config looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\RawMaterialsSystem.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: f01b1621-2ced-4ad2-9ae6-004e03b0e043-->`
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Read IIS log files to know the sub status first if the error page does not show you yet.

Comment: Can you try adding swagger then open swaggerui to see how your API looks like

Comment: Is this using the Angular VS or dotnet template? Does the web server have nodejs installed? Are you running the published files in Development mode (which I think is the default)? It might be that the Angular Spa middleware is failing to find resources at the nodejs server that isn't running?

Comment: the IIS log shows this 
  2018-05-27 23:24:28 127.0.0.1 GET / - 88 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+Touch;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 404 0 0 15

Comment: wilmsaccnt - It was first built as an angular project,  but then I built it again as just a plain dotnet one and separated the front end completely.  Nodejs is NOT on the server.  Do I need it and what for?  Environment is set to Development... does that control the publish mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STEP 1: Change your web.config file to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

STEP 2:

- In visual studio, right click the .net core app project and select "Publish"
- Then publish it as a folder under bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\publish

STEP 3:

- In IIS --> Sites --> Right click on *YourSite* --> Under "Manage Website" select "Advanced Settings"
- Make sure the "Physical Path" you are pointing to is the "publish" folder as the app directory, and not the "netcoreapp2.0" folder

Comment: it was the PATH setting in the published web.config.  It needed to be path="" for mine to work.

Comment: @goneos How does that even work? It says 'The 'path' attribute is invalid. String must not be empty'

Comment: sorry @ΕГИІИО.  I'm no longer working at that place and don't have access to the config anymore.  Not sure how it worked with an emptuy path... maybe it caused some sort of default to be used?

Comment: I am pointing my website to c:\solutionfolder\projectfolder\bin\Release\net5.0\publish where my web.config is. I get: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: Without web.config I continue getting: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found