# webservice returns "not found" when run on IIS server on another machine

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

I am writing a webservice with some API's, and I have it working fine on my development computer, but when I install it on my IIS server, I keep getting "not found"

In the webserver the route to the API looks like this

```
using gttWebServicePlatform.Models;
using gttWebServicePlatform.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace gttWebServicePlatform.Controllers
{
    [Route("vla/AppLogin")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AppLoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly RepositoryAppLogin _repositoryAppLogin = new();

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AppLogin(ModelAppLoginRequest appLoginRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                return base.Ok(_repositoryAppLogin.GetAppLogin(appLoginRequest));
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                return base.BadRequest("Nope not working...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in my testclient I call it like this

```
 private async void AppLogin()
 {
     ModelAppLoginRequest appLoginRequest = new ModelAppLoginRequest()
     {
         TruckPlate = gttDXTextEdit3.Text,
         Password = gttDXTextEdit2.Text,
         DateEvent = DateTime.Now,
         GPSLocation = gttDXTextEdit1.Text
     };

     string JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appLoginRequest);
     System.Net.Http.StringContent restContent = new StringContent(JsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     try
     {
         var response = await client.PostAsync(comboBoxEdit2.Text, restContent);
                
         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             ModelAppLoginResponse Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelAppLoginResponse>(stream);

             textBox2.Text = Result.Authorized.ToString() + " " + Result.TruckID.ToString(); //Result.SCS_ID + " " + Result.PaymentID;
         }
         else
         {
             textBox2.Text = response.StatusCode + " " + response.ReasonPhrase;
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         textBox2.Text = ex.Message;
     }

 }
```

If I run the webservice from VS on my local computer, and then run the testclient with this url `http://localhost:20857/vla/AppLogin` then it works

If I use this url `http://SRV-GTT-IIS02:8089/vla/AppLogin` then I immediate get the response "not found"

I have other webservices running on that IIS service, they all work without problems, I checked the properties with those and I can't see any problem.

In the log files of IIS I found this

```
2022-10-28 16:42:04
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2022-10-28 16:42:04 192.168.137.185 POST /vla/AppLogin - 8089 - 192.168.137.144 - - 404 0 2 1359
2022-10-28 16:52:45 127.0.0.1 GET / - 8089 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:106.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/106.0 - 403 14 0 41
2022-10-28 16:52:45 127.0.0.1 GET /favicon.ico - 8089 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:106.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/106.0 http://localhost:8089/ 404 0 64 41
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2022-10-28 16:57:17
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2022-10-28 16:57:17 192.168.137.185 POST /vla/AppLogin - 8089 - 192.168.137.144 - - 404 0 2 219
```

From this I think I can make out that ISS has been reached, but somehow my method has not been found.
I have no clue what this logfile means, so I am just guessing here.

Does anyone has an idea in what direction I have to start looking ?
The port is open in the firewall, the IIS log suggest it is reachable, what else can I still do ?

**EDIT 1**

If I stop the site in IIS and try again with my testclient, than I receive a timeout after some time, so the call must arrive at the site after all. It is almost as if the site cannot find the method when it is run on IIS, but can find the method when run from visual studio.
Does that makes any sense ?

**EDIT 2**

### Installation in IIS:

I found all these files here (done by a colleague who is not working here anymore)
I copied the files from the BIN directory of the working project in Visual Studio there, so I am sure I have the same files there as I have in the working VS

[image]

### This is the configuration in IIS

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit 3 The site CAN be reached**

If I enable directory browsing, and try to reach the site on the server from my local computer, I do get to see the directory.
So now I am sure that the correct site is reached, it just does not finds the method when run in IIS while it does finds the method when run in VS (ISS Express I believe)

see these screens

This I get when I try another method on the server

[image]

and when I do the same when running local from VS

[image]

**EDIT 4 When running the executable on the server, that also works**

If I remote desktop the server, and start the executable in the command prompt, and then test with the testclient also on the remote machine, it works, so it only does not finds the method if I call it from somewhere else ? I am so confused

[image]

Comment: We need to know how exactly you deployed it to IIS (steps and screen shots). Otherwise, nobody should guess and waste time.

Comment: @LexLi I am not an expert on IIS, So I made some screenshots, just ask me what else you wish to see

Comment: Based on the limited information provided, I can see this is an ASP.NET Core web app deployed to Windows/IIS. What I suggest is from scratch you go through the tutorial from Microsoft, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio on a clean web app and a clean site, so as to master the very basics. Then you can go back and check what's wrong with this customized web app.

Comment: What more information can I provide ? It seems to me this web app is working perfect, until it  has to run under IIS

Comment: @LexLi I have read this tutorial, and removed the site and then reinstalled using the steps in this tutorial, but I have the same results. What more information do you need to see ? What can I provide ?

Comment: Just take another look of the whole story. A POST action won't respond to the browser (which by default sends GET). Thus, 404.0 is rather normal.

Comment: @LexLi I don't understand your comment, but either way, it also does not respond to a GET either, it also don't show the page either. This works perfect in ISS Express but not in regular IIS, reinstalled 3 times today, using [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-5-0-application-in-windows-server-iis/) guide, but no results

Comment: When you use this URL `http://SRV-GTT-IIS02:8089/vla/AppLogin`, you will get a `"Not Found"` response immediately. Is `SRV-GTT-IIS02` your domain name? When you deployed your website in IIS, did you bind it to the `Host name`?

Comment: that is the name of the server where IIS is installed, and where I publised the web ap

Comment: @LexLi I used the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50528697/net-core-api-not-working-on-iis) question, now I do not get "not found" anymore, but now I always get a blank page. Also when I try an API I just get a blank page, while in ISS Express it still works normal

Comment: @YurongDai  I used the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50528697/net-core-api-not-working-on-iis) question, now I do not get "not found" anymore, but now I always get a blank page. Also when I try an API I just get a blank page, while in ISS Express it still works normal

Comment: When you get a blank page, what is the status code returned? It is recommended that you use the FRT to trace the error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis